# User account working as administrator - not wanted

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, uac

I have the opposite problem as many of those who make questions about Admin accounts here.

My PC failed, so I did a factory reset thus reinstalling `Win 10 Pro` from scratch.

- I first created a local account which had administrator,
- then I created an Admin account,
- logged under this one and lowered the first account to user account.

Unfortunately when I am logged as the normal user account (Peppe in the screenshot) if I try to install a program or do anything else which triggers UAC, I am asked only to confirm the UAC.
Before the reset I had to insert the password or PIN of the Admin account in order to continue, and that is the wanted behavior, because I want to be in control of what each program is doing.
Could you please help me to have the password/PIN prompt when I trigger UAC?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to make the change from administrator to user in the settings->accounts page, or it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The new rights will only apply once you have logged out of the account whose rights were changed. Try logging out, then logging in again.

If this doesn't work, does creating a new user account give it proper rights ? If so, it may be easier to create a new account and migrate the old account's data to the new one.

Comment: Hi Arno, thanks a lot, you were definitely right. It works like a charm now, after logging out. Apologies for the stupid question.